# Git push current branch(not master) to new repo

Tags: git

I have a repo with two branches with name **master** and **branchA**. I need to push the current local **branchA** to new different git repo. On executing the below commands:

```
   git remote set-url **rep -url**
   git push origin master
```

My master is being pushed to new git repo. Although i have to push the branchA to the remote.

**Note :-** On local, i am on branchA

Please help

Comment: *"My master is being pushed to new git repo. Although i have to push the branchA to the remote."* -- You ran `git push origin master`. What would you expect? Git does what you tell it to do, it cannot read your mind. Don't push `master`, put `branchA` instead of `master` in the [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) command.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you change the origin remote? You can instead add another remote.

```
git remote add remote-for-branchA **url**
git push remote-for-branchA branchA
```

This should push your branchA to the remote-for-branchA remote.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It is same what i am already doing. Please check before down voting the question . I want to push the current branchA to remote. Not the master to remote.

Comment: @IshantGaurav I guess it was just a typo, given the general meaning of his answer. Fixed. Am i slightly late here? ':-)